# Divergent series in a finite interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

Is it possible to construct coefficients $u_n$ such that series $\sum_{=1}^{\infty} u_k \sin kx$ diverges to infinity in a finite interval say if $x\in[\pi/7,\pi/6]$ and converges otherwise?

Comment: Do you mean in every point of the intervall $[\pi/7,\pi/6]$?

Comment: Yes every point

Comment: Do you mean that the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n u_k \sin kx\to+\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ exactly for all $x\in[\pi/7,\pi/6]$, despite the oscillating behavior of the summands? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yes exactly. Thank you for comment.